# Android Studio can't generate an unsigned apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I built an app and I want to generate an unsigned .apk for that.

```
Build > Build APK
```

Gradle build runs and finishes without any error but when I check

```
Build > outputs > apk
```

path, I can't see any unsigned apk folder, only `app-debug-unaligned.apk` and `app-debug.apk` exist.

Comment: `app-debug.apk` is your unsigned apk

Comment: This is the apk which gets loaded if you are directly connecting your device. app-debug.apk  This is unassigned apk. For creating signed APK, you need to go through following process with which in the specified destination folder signed apk will be created. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: So I can only use an unsigned apk for debugging and testing right?

Comment: No you can debug and test with any apk that has the "Debuggable" flag set in its build type. Debug type has this by default but Release type does not.. For example, I create a 3rd build type called "Signed" that is signed AND debuggable so that when I use a different computer, it doesn't complain that there is a signature mismatch. Play Store will not allow you to upload an APK with the debuggable flag set so there is no risk.

Comment: app-debug.apk is the unsigned apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer .. You should select release buildVariant then use build apk to get unsigned-apk .. otherwise by default you are using debug buildType which using debug keystore for signing apk ..

**Unsigned apk cannot be installed on any device/emulator unless it is signed**

So using build apk on:

**Debug** buildType will sign apk with debug keystore

**Release** builtType will produce unsigned.apk ..

Both are available on [project dir]/app/build/outputs/apk/

FYI: **Why Android studio doesn't sign release builType implicitly as debug?**

Thats done on purpose to prevent developers to use debug keystore by mistake to sign apk as release buildType which may go to play store ..

You have two solutions to sign release:

1. (Easier) Go to build (menu) ==> generate Signed APK and then create
   once a keystore then use it to sign apk.
2. If you want achieve that by command so update build.gradle to
   guide compiler to your own keystore . my favorite approach is here :
   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html
   Then use (for step #2)

   ```
   ./gradlew assembleRelease
   ```

   to have signed apk with your own keystore

I hope that may help,'.